# "Звездочки" в import - хорошо ли использовать ?

Tags: java

Например, вместо

```
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.layout.VLayout;
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.layout.HLayout;
```

можно писать

```
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.layout.*;
```

и все работает.

Хорошо ли это (использовать '*') ?

Возникает ли дополнительная нагрузка на компилятор (на глаз не ощущается), объем подключаемого кода (не исследовал) и т.п. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интересной и неприятной стороной импорта всех классов из пакета может стать ситуация, когда в пакет добавляются классы:

```
package a;

import b.*; // тут есть класс B
import c.*; // тут есть класс С

public class A {
    public A() {
        new B();
        new C();
    }
}
```

Фокус произойдет, если в пакет b добавится вдруг класс С - наш класс перестанет компилироваться. Обновили какую-нибудь библиотеку и бац - ни с того, ни с сего. Еще бывает ситуации, когда неясно, из какого именно пакета импортирован класс.

Минусом поименного импорта является большое "полотно" собственно импортов - но оно практически всегда скрыто ("collapsed") в редакторе.

Cам я, честно говоря, этим никогда не заморачивался - Eclipse импортирует поименно - и пусть себе импортирует. Мне кажется, минусы любого подхода сейчас хорошо компенсируются современными IDE.

Comment: Да, собственно глядя на полотно импортов в Eclipse, я этим и заинтересовался.

Всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Конкретно по Eclipse - максимальное количество импортов из одного пакета настраивается: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Organize Imports

Comment: ^^ Ctrl+O или Ctrl+Shift+O,
а вообще для эклипса лучше настроить выполнение этого действия при сохранении: 
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Clean up; Edit -> Code orginizing --> Imports: Orginize imports [x]

Answer (score 2):

Все должно быть в разумных пределах. Если нужно один класс импортировать, то можно и написать его полный путь, но когда в импорте перечисляется половина классов модуля, то какой смысл? Хотя некоторые эстеты найдут это правильным.
Нагрузка на компилятор? Сложно что то сказать, и никогда не слышал, что бы кто то это исследовал, но вот повыбрасывать явно лишние импорты - стоит (может по этой причине и импортируют все явно?)
А вот будет ли больше объем подключаемого кода? я думаю компилятор может все очень хорошо оптимизировать.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно я не прав, но если я не ошибаюсь, то нагрузки на компилятор вообще никакой от этих строк нет.

Компилятор не включает указанные классы в саму программу (.jar файл). Это всего навсего ссылки, по которым виртуальная машина будет искать классы в процессе выполнения программы.

То есть если если и есть лишняя нагрузка, то только в рантайме.

И еще, иногда могут встречаться такие ситуации (пример на вскидку привести не могу, но такое может случится), когда в разных пакетах лежат классы с одинаковыми именами. О таких ситуациях стоит помнить, когда вы ставите много *.

Comment: если import перечисляет все пакеты в классе - то увеличивается время компиляции(особенно если это большие пакеты). Однако на время выполнения и размер класса никак не влияет. (П. Ноутон, Г. Шилдт Справочник по Java)